# asp:HyperLink and url stored in DB is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tring to give the ExtLinkHPLINK a value of extlink column which is external URL stored in this column. But what is happening when i put the mouse on the hyperlink it not show me that there is a way to click it and move to external URL in other way the hyperlink doesnt work and not moving me to the url. So what i suppose to do

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top:48px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">

                      For more images and information <asp:HyperLink ID="ExtLinkHPLINK" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("extlink") %>'>click here</asp:HyperLink>     
                                </div>
          </div>

SqlConnection shwadsone = new SqlConnection(cs);
        {

            shwadsone.Open();
            SqlCommand adsdeCM = new SqlCommand();
  string adsdetSqlSelect = @"SELECT AD.[AdsID],AD.[UID],AD.[Section],AD.[Category],AD.[Country],AD.[State],AD.[City],AD.[AdsTit] /...,UI.[Logo],UI.[Img],UI.[TeleNum],UI.[Email], FROM [ads] as AD JOIN UserInfo as UI ON AD.[UID] = UI.[UID] where AD.AdsID = @AID ";showernumlbl.Text = adsdetDR["Shower"].ToString();
                carmakerlbl.Text = adsdetDR["Maker"].ToString();
                Label2.Text = adsdetDR["Garage"].ToString();
                CountCurrencLbl.Text = adsdetDR["Currency"].ToString();
                ExtLinkHPLINK.NavigateUrl = adsdetDR["extlink"].ToString();/...
```

Comment: use Inspect element of chrome or firefox to see outout html of link and see whats wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in your design page:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top:48px; padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        For more images and information 
        <asp:HyperLink ID="ExtLinkHPLINK" runat="server" Target="_blank">click here</asp:HyperLink>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Your code behind:

```
string adsdetSqlSelect = @"select AD.[AdsID],
                                  AD.[UID],
                                  AD.[Section],
                                  AD.[Category],
                                  AD.[Country],
                                  AD.[State],
                                  AD.[City],
                                  AD.[AdsTit],
                                  UI.[Logo],
                                  UI.[Img],
                                  UI.[TeleNum],
                                  UI.[Email]
                             from [ads] as AD 
                             join UserInfo as UI 
                               ON AD.[UID] = UI.[UID] 
                            where AD.AdsID = @AID";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand adsdeCM = new SqlCommand(adsdetSqlSelect, con);
try{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sdr.Read();
    showernumlbl.Text = sdr["Shower"].ToString();
    carmakerlbl.Text = sdr["Maker"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = sdr["Garage"].ToString();
    CountCurrencLbl.Text = sdr["Currency"].ToString();
    ExtLinkHPLINK.NavigateUrl = sdr["extlink"].ToString();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //Catch exceptions and work with them
}
finally{
    con.Close();
}
```

I don't know your tables structure, so I just hope that you really have *Shower*, *Maker*, *Garage*, *Currency*, *extlink* fields in your tables and that that fields are just in one table. Otherwise you have to rename them in query using *as* instruction. Hope it helps